# How to use nginx proxy_pass with subdomains?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to pass requests like this:

```
  http://mydomain.io --> http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://mydomain.io/aa/bb --> http://127.0.0.1:8080/aa/bb
  http://api.mydomain.io --> http://127.0.0.1:10000
  http://api.mydomain.io/cc/dd --> http://127.0.0.1:10000/cc/dd
```

and my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file:

```
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.io;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.mydomain.io;

  location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/$1;
  }
}
```

When I send request to `http://api.mydomain.io:10000/xxx`, it works,

but `http://api.mydomain.io/xxx` doesn't work.
(It returns 502 Bad Gateway Error)

What is the problem with my config file?

Answer (score 1):

default.conf

```
server { # This one before the wilcard domain
    listen 80;
    server_name api.mydomain.io;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000;
    }
}

server { # always at the end
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name *.mydomain.io;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```